# Service Fabric Config disk location

Tags: security, azure, configuration-files, azure-service-fabric

I'm using Service Fabric's configuration system, and storing connection strings for a SQL database and some blob storage, in environment-specific application parameter files, as detailed here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration

Best practice for application security dictates that secrets should not be kept in plaintext in configuration files, so I'm trying to figure out what to do about this situation.

However, when I RDP to the Service Fabric cluster nodes, I can't find those config files anywhere. Can anyone tell me where these files are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect your secrets like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-secret-management).

And you can find the files of your service by using the Service Fabric Explorer. First go to the Node you're RDP'ing into, then select your Application instance, it'll show a Disk Location. That's where your Service files are.